# Using grid events

Tags: dojo

Would anyone let me know how to refresh a grid depending on your selection from another grid. I'm looking at the example at

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/dojox/data/demos/demo_QueryReadStore_grid.html

Is there is any way that the second grid can be updated once you click on any row in the first one. For example Assume that the first table has only the state names and the second one has the capitals. When I click on the State on the first table I only want to see the capital for that state at the second grid.

Please let me know if you have an answer for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, using refresh grid to change the store, and the layout of the other grid if necessary using the text value.

```
grid.onCellClick = function(e) {
    refreshGrid(e.cellNode.innerHTML);
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't dojo.connect be used to bind to the onRowClick(e) event?  I'm trying to do the same thing, but I'm having trouble setting up a listener function using dojo.connect for handling a dojox.grid.dataGrid event.